# SfBApplication *sfb = SfBApplication.sharedApplication;

Tags: skypedeveloper

SfBApplication *sfb = SfBApplication.sharedApplication;

the sfb   always return nil，can you help me ?why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation you can read that the return value is :

`Shared application instance or @a nil if initialization fails`

Have you followed the instructions from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/howtojoinmeeting_ios) ? 
Especially the import part :

```
#import <SkypeForBusiness/SkypeForBusiness.h>
#import "SfBConversationHelper.h"
```

Have you also added the `ConversationHelper`Class to your source ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your AVSession? I had SFB crashed before I configured it.